# GLFW callback signature in Swift 3

Tags: c, swift, swift3, glfw

I'm trying to setup a simple GLFW application in Swift 3. Currently I'm stuck trying to set a callback function.

```
func setupGLFW() {
  ...
  glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback)
  ...
}

func errorCallback(error: Int32, description: UnsafePointer<Int8>) {
  ...
}
```

This worked in Swift 2 but now I get this error:

> cannot convert value of type '(Int32, UnsafePointer) -> ()' to expected argument type 'GLFWerrorfun!'

After consulting the section **Interacting with C APIs** in the documentation, I also tried this signature:

```
func errorCallback(error: CInt, description: UnsafePointer<CChar>) {
  ...
}
```

This leads to the same error.

The C signature for `GLFWerrorfun` is:

```
typedef void(* GLFWerrorfun) (int, const char *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
func errorCallback(error: Int32, description: UnsafePointer<Int8>?) {
```

(Please do not miss the `?` after `UnsafePointer<Int8>`.)

In Swift 3, nullable pointer are imported as Optional pointer, so you need `?`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the callback inline where you call `glfwSetErrorCallback`:

```
glfwSetErrorCallback { (error, description) in
    //
}
```

Or, use a closure stored in a variable:

```
let callback: GLFWerrorfun = { (error, description) in
    //
}

glfwSetErrorCallback(callback)
```

You can see how this typedef is bridged to Swift by Option + Left Clicking on the symbol:

[image: GLFWerrorfun typealias]

In this case I didn't have the actual GLFW headers, so I just dropped the declaration in a Bridging Header.  Your generated interface may show more information.

Comment: Thank you! Though decision, but I accepted OOPers answer because it shows the exact signature.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss You realize that you can add the types to the parameters in my answer too right?  And what happens if Swift changes the types again?  You'll be back here asking the same question.  Generally, I prefer to let the compiler infer the parameter type.

Comment: For actual code I also prefer type inference, but OOPers answer helped me understand why my signature didn't match.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss You can also see how the C type is bridged to Swift by Option + Left Clicking on the symbol to view the generated interface.